# C++ convertion char int ARM

Tags: c++, arm

I have this very simple C++ code :

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << (int)(char)(int)char(-2);
    return 0;
}
```

I am executing it on different setups :

- Ubuntu 20.04 x64 (g++)        ->  Output : -2
- Windows 10 x64 MSVC 2017      ->  Output : -2
- MacOS x64 Clang -> Output -2
- Ubuntu Armv8 (g++) / EC2 Instance ->  Output : 254

I want to obtain -2 all the time, and I don't understand this difference in behavior.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: I think this answer covers what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2054959/47453. Although it's tagged [c] instead of [c++].

Comment: tip: don't make too many steps at once.  You should get same output with `std::cout << char(-2);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A compiler is allowed to choose if `char` is signed or unsigned. The standard says that they have to pick, but don't mandate which way they choose.

GCC supports `-fsigned-char` and `-funsigned-char` to force this behavior.

Comment: Is it only with the "char" type?

Comment: @BlackPopa: Googling around, gives the likely reason being that loading a signed char into memory is more expensive than loading an unsigned char. https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=18270359

Comment: @BlackPopa: `char` is the only one that behaves this way. The others are signed by default.

Answer (score 3):

From the ISO C++ International Standard (Tip of trunk):

| ### §6.8.2 Fundamental Types | ### [[basic.fundamental]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.types#basic.fundamental) |
| --- | --- |

> [7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.types#basic.fundamental-7) - *Type char is a distinct type that has an implementation-defined choice of “signed char” or “unsigned char” as its underlying type.*
>
> [...]

Not much more to add about that.

Compiler vendors are free to choose whichever one they like or feel that is more reasonable given the target architecture, for ARM architectures [it seems that unsigned char is preferred](https://godbolt.org/z/n4M8bfzz9).

It appears that the reason behind this is the fact that older versions of ARM, prior to ARMv4, had no native support for loading halfwords and signed bytes, so `char` became `unsigned` by default, and `unsigned` it remains, for legacy reasons.

Main source:

http://www.davespace.co.uk/arm/efficient-c-for-arm/memaccess.html

Answer (score 0):

The shown output is consistent with `char` being an unsigned data type on the platform in question. The C++ standard allows `char` to be equivalent to either `unsigned char` or `signed char`.

If you wish a specific behavior you can explicitly use a cast to `signed char` in your code.

Comment: nitpick: `char` is either signed or unsigned, but in either case it is a type distinct from `signed char` and `unsigned char`